# Neo4j Cypher: If you create multiple elements, you can only create one of each

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I'm trying to create a tree using a really basic parameterised cypher command, but I'm getting this error whenever I try to create more than one item at a time:

> If you create multiple elements, you can only create one of each.

```
{
  "query" :  "MATCH (p) WHERE p.id='Hello' CREATE (c {props}), p-[r:CHILD]->c",
  "params" : {  
      "props" : [ {
         "type": 44,
         "title" : "TestNode"
       },{
         "type": 45,
         "title" : "TestNode"
       } ]
    }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an array of maps in the `CREATE` statement, you cannot also create relationships in the same statement.

> By providing Cypher an array of maps, it will create a node for each map. When you do this, you can’t create anything else in the same CREATE statement.

[See it in the docs here.](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-create.html)

All you need to do is add another `CREATE` statement:

```
{
  "query" :  "MATCH (p) WHERE p.id='Hello' CREATE (c {props}) CREATE UNIQUE p-[:CHILD]->c",
  "params" : {  
      "props" : [ {
         "type": 44,
         "title" : "TestNode"
         },{
         "type": 45,
         "title" : "TestNode"
       } ]
    }
 }
```